# Bruteforcing zip file gives weird results

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, zip, brute-force

So I wrote this program to bruteforce a zip file in python:

```
def Main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("zfile", help = "The encrypted zip file you wish to crack")
    parser.add_argument("length", help="Define the max length of password combinations you want to bruteforce")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    zFile = zipfile.ZipFile(args.zfile)
    keywords = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(ascii_lowercase, repeat = int(args.length))]

    for i in keywords:
        print "[*] Testing password: "+i
        try:
            zFile.extractall(pwd = str(i))
            print "[+] Password Found: "+i
            break
        except:
            pass    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

But it's behaving unusually.... I have an archive in which the password is "dog", and when I run the program, it finds a whole bunch of passwords that supposedly "work" but don't actually. If  I manually type these passwords into the zip file, it extracts a corrupted file.
The program said passwords such as "aqw" would work, and there were quite a few of these. The weirdest part was that the program wouldn't break from the for loop after it said that one of these non-functioning passwords would work.

I have no idea what's going on!

Comment: I have two questions about this sentence: "If I type manually such passwords into the zip file, it extracts a corrupted file."  (1) what do you mean by typing a password into a zip file? I would think that a password gets typed into a program rather than a zip file; the program then extracts the data from the file.  What program are you using?  (2) What is the "it" that extracts a corrupted file?  Your program as listed doesn't print anything when a trial password fails.  Are you sure that this ever happens?

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase all of that. I have an archive, and when I try to decompress it using Stuffit Expander, it prompts me for a password. I know that the password is "dog". However, when I run my script, it outputs several other passwords, such as "aqw" or "how" (ex. the program will print "[+] Password Found: how"), saying that those will work when I try to expand the zip file. When i type these passwords into Stuffit Expander, they will actually extract the zip file, but the extracted file will be corrupted. Sorry I made that massive typo

Comment: thanks, makes sense now.  I'm not sure you have a Python problem, since Stuffit Expander and Python are consistent: neither one of them gives you an invalid password result when they're supposed to.  I looked at the zipfile.py code (standard Python library) and it uses something called _ZipDecrypter which is written in pure Python.  When it fails you get a RuntimeException("Bad password for file"), but it's not very sophisticated.  Maybe looking at the library source will give you a clue.  Strange problem.

Comment: Do you think it's maybe a security feature built in to the zip file so you can't brute force it?

Comment: I think it's more likely that the password feature isn't that good.  Perhaps it relies in part on humans, rather than programs, detecting bad decryption.  From my reading of the Python code it seems that the password itself isn't stored in the zip file, so the algorithm can't literally check for a match.  Instead it tries to infer the correctness of the guessed password, and doesn't always get it right.  Unfortunately in that case, the program you want to write will never work.  I could be all wrong however.

Answer (score 4):

That is happening because the ZIP file format uses a very crude method for determining if the password entered is in fact correct or incorrect.

Basically, there is a single byte stored in the archive’s directory that indicates that the password is “correct”. The problem is that when you’re bruteforcing, you will very frequently trigger false positives where the byte matches (probably once every 255 tries or so), but the password is not actually correct.

When you find such a potential match, the idea is to fully decrypt the archive using that password. Once it is fully decrypted the program should compare the CRC of the decrypted data with the stored CRC and check if the password was in fact, correct.

That’s the only way you’ll know for sure that a match has been found.

Comment: Exactly. I'd also add that what is usually done to remove false positives like this, is to test the password on multiple files from the archive (using multiple test bytes in the process). Assuming you have more than one file in your archive.